# Webpage not responsive allthough having bootstrap with meta tag (Redmine)

Tags: html, css, ruby, erb, redmine

I'm currently working on an redmine app.
I want the page to be responsive, but it doesn't really work, although I have the meta tag included.

The Redmine header/banner is not shown on the page, but I noticed that the code is still there. Maybe this is the problem? If so, how can I fully remove the code for this page?

This is the code of the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Redmine</title>
<meta name="description" content="Redmine" />
<meta name="keywords" content="issue,bug,tracker" />
<meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" />
<meta content="zAhdWOwD3KiOanSXnXiNPIT0NzBRFQwbsH1y4wkiqww=" name="csrf-token" />
<link rel='shortcut icon' href='/favicon.ico?1459352855' />
<link href="/stylesheets/jquery/jquery-ui-1.11.0.css?1459352855" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/stylesheets/application.css?1459352855" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="/javascripts/jquery-1.11.1-ui-1.11.0-ujs-3.1.3.js?1459352855" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/application.js?1459352855" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
$(window).load(function(){ warnLeavingUnsaved('Die aktuellen Änderungen gehen verloren, wenn Sie diese Seite verlassen.'); });
//]]>
</script>


<!-- page specific tags -->

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link href="/plugin_assets/redmine_mtr/stylesheets/styles.css?1459353025" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=20, initial-scale=1">

    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


</head>
<body class="controller-mtr_account action-mtr_login">
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="wrapper2">
<div id="wrapper3">
<div id="top-menu">
    <div id="account">
        <ul><li><a href="/login" class="login">Anmelden</a></li>
<li><a href="/account/register" class="register">Registrieren</a></li></ul>    </div>

    <ul><li><a href="/" class="home">Hauptseite</a></li>
<li><a href="/projects" class="projects">Projekte</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.redmine.org/guide" class="help">Hilfe</a></li></ul></div>

<div id="header">
    <div id="quick-search">
        <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/search" method="get"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /></div>

        <label for='q'>
          <a href="/search" accesskey="4">Suche</a>:
        </label>
        <input accesskey="f" class="small" id="q" name="q" size="20" type="text" />
</form>        
    </div>

    <h1>Redmine</h1>

</div>

<div id="main" class="nosidebar">
    <div id="sidebar">


    </div>

    <div id="content">

        <div id="login-form" class="col-sm-12 modal show" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/mtr/login" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="zAhdWOwD3KiOanSXnXiNPIT0NzBRFQwbsH1y4wkiqww=" /></div>

        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h1 class="container col-md-12">Login</h1>
                    <h5 class="container col-md-12">Mobile Time Recording</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body form-group">
                    <div style="padding-top: 5px;">
                        <input class="login-input" id="username" name="username" style="width: 100%" tabindex="1" type="text" />
                    </div>
                    <div style="padding-top: 5px;">
                        <input class="login-input" id="password" name="password" style="width: 100%" tabindex="2" type="password" />
                    </div>
                    <div style="padding-top: 5px;">
                        <input type="submit" style="height: 38px" class="form-control input-lg btn btn-danger"
                               name="loginMtr" value="Anmelden &#187;" tabindex="5"/>
                    </div>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
</form></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
$('#username').focus();
//]]>
</script>


        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<div id="ajax-indicator" style="display:none;"><span>Lade...</span></div>
<div id="ajax-modal" style="display:none;"></div>

<div id="footer">
  <div class="bgl"><div class="bgr">
    Powered by <a href="http://www.redmine.org/">Redmine</a> &copy; 2006-2015 Jean-Philippe Lang
  </div></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why are you setting the width of the viewport (BTW 20 is not a valid size anyway since it has no unit of measure)? The tag usually looks like `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` This means that the view port will be handled based on the device itself. However you need to make sure none of your elements have a fixed width greater than the view port or you will get horizontal scrolling. This requires most if not all elements to have a fluid width based on relative sizes like `%`, `em`, `ex`, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your help so far. I don't know how that width got there, it is now set to device-width. I also set the widths of all my elements to a percentage and I still got horizontal scrolling.

Comment: You would be better off using the classes that bootstrap provides for sizing `col-xx-##` and using [`fluid containers`](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-container) as container to bootstrap means fixed width.

Answer (score 0):

I would first recommend that you use bootstrap and jQuery CDN rather then the files. The reason for this is to help with your asset pipeline and also to future proof your code - for example... if your jQuery lib goes out of date - you would have to manually go back and update it. Rather then just attaching a CDN and its forgetting it.

Second its best practice to always move all your JavaScript src tags to the end of your page before the ending `</body>` tag.

Also if you could update the problem with an error that you are running into - that may be a bit more helpful. Its best if you keep your developer tools open when making a website (helps to see what errors you run into on the DOM).